# How to change the Selection activecell in sheetview using OpenXml?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I need to remove this Selection activecell and it can be done by assigning it to A1. But I could not figure out the tag hierarchy I should be using.
I used the following code.But it is not working.

```
            WorkbookPart wbPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
            var workbook = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook;

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = wbPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetViews sheetViews = worksheet.SheetViews;
            SheetView sheetView = sheetViews.Descendants<SheetView>().First();
            var selection = sheetView.Descendants<Selection>().First();
            selection.ActiveCell = "A1";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is the remove the selected cell then you just need to replace your last two lines with

```
sheetView.RemoveAllChildren();
```

IF you also want to make sure that A1 is the top left cell in view then you should also add the following line

```
sheetView.TopLeftCell = "A1";
```

Also be sure to save the worksheet with

```
worksheet.Save();
```